# NodeJS child_process: run two process in parallel over ssh and stream outputs

Tags: node.js, ssh, parallel-processing, stream, child-process

First off, this could have been easily accomplished with [ssh2](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ssh2), but I could not use it because [it does not support certificate authentication](https://github.com/mscdex/ssh2/issues/551).

Hence the problem at hand:

I am using `child_process` to run the `ssh binary` and connect to a remote server. I can run commands and get their outputs via `stdin` and `stdout` of the spawned process. But I have a use case where I need to run **two commands in parallel**. One is a long running command which I need to stream line by line and the other is a lightweight command whose input depends on the contents of the streamed lines. Is it possible to do this **without spawning two** `ssh` processes?

Workarounds using ssh2 or something similar are also welcome.

**(Edit)Adding a descriptive example:**

`Process 1` is long running and keeps writing lines to stdout/file, `Process 2` needs to run on each line as whenever a line is produced by `Process 1`. At each point, when `Process 2` for a line completes, I need both `input line printed by Process 1` and `the corresponding output of Process 2`

Answer (score 0):

there is a very simple way: use gnu parallel.
https://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/
It is installed on Ubuntu f.e. with `sudo apt -y install parallel`

```
ssh host \
  'echo -e "date > 1.out && sleep 5\n date > 2.out && sleep 5" | parallel -j0'
ssh host cat 1.out
    > Th 14. Jun 10:54:15 CEST 2018
ssh host cat 2.out
    > Th 14. Jun 10:54:15 CEST 2018
```

Now you could ssh to cat 1.out and 2.out.

But let's consider your later edit:

prog1.sh:

```
for i in {1..5}; do
  echo $i >> 1.out
  sleep 1;
done
echo "done" >> 1.out
sleep 1
echo -e "\n" >> 1.out
```

prog2.sh (monitors 1.out and does some command, here tail):

```
inotifywait -e close_write,moved_to,create -m . |
  while read -r directory events filename; do
    if [ "$filename" = "1.out" ]; then
      # 1.out changed we need to do something
      res=$(tail -1 1.out)
        if [ $res = "done" ]; then
            break;
        fi
      fi
  done

ssh host 'echo -e "./prog2.sh \n ./prog1.sh" | parallel -j 2'
```

Comment: But I need the output streams separately for the first and second process. How do I accomplish this with parallel?

Comment: let me see. interesting.

Comment: Quite close but my problem is slightly more complicated, I've added a more descriptive example to the question

Comment: the rest is programming really. i just showed you how to start 2 programs in parallel remotely. the mechanism that you describe is a programming issue of two programs which interact. so the first call above stays as is. the second program needs to monitor file events on the 1.out and do things. but again, this is a programming issue. what programming language is process 2 written in? fdo you have the code?

Comment: Actually I am not in control of these two processes as they are both standard unix commands. And I do not have write access on the server to write a wrapper program/script. Maybe there's a different approach altogether than parallel?

Comment: if you'd write the code, one could see, how to solve your specific issue.

Comment: Here's a quick code I wrote with node-ssh: https://codeshare.io/5N9Yr4. This does exactly what I need but unfortunately I cannot use this because of the authentication issue.

Comment: did you see my update above. the rest can be done with all of the above that i wrote together. would appreciate, if you accepted the answer, if you see fit.

Comment: Sorry I missed it, this looks like it does the job. I was afraid it might get this ugly. Sure there's no cleaner way to do this? I really can't rely on markers as the `echo $i >> 1.out` output in my case is not under my control and I would have to make sure my marker ("done" in your code) is unique.